# laravel eloquent where in query not working on both array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

How to use `$a` variable in wherein properly? My code is as follows:

```
$color = json_decode($request -> color); //["2","3"] from jquery ajax
$a;

foreach($color as $k){
    $a[] = $k;
}

$b =[2,3];
$query = $query->whereIn('color', $a);
```

When I put `$a` array in whereIn, only one record is fetched. But if i add `$b` array then all records are fetched. I don't know what is the issue of both arrays.

Comment: Where is `$query` initialized? And what model is used?

Comment: directly its only showing one record.

Comment: $query = Products::query();

Comment: Don't know if it's the solution but I would try to instantiate `$a` as `$a = [];` or `$a = array();` so it's an array before the `foreach` loop begins

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to convert every element in the array to integer:

```
$query->whereIn('color', array_map('intval', json_decode($request->color)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your array values to integer

```
 foreach($color as $k){
        $a[]= (int) $k;
    }
```